# Corelocation Crashs

Tags: ios, core-location

I am using corelocation in my app, it retrieves the lat/lon as desired but when I "back" out of that page (    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES]; ) The app crashes.

I dont get any errors, can only assume I am not quitting the update location properly??

Any help?

Thanks

Comment: What message does it give when it crashes?

Comment: No message given, just crashes.

Comment: What do the crash logs say in the Organizer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is rather vague, but I guess the *page* you are referring to is the delegate of your CLLocationManager. Your *page* gets deallocated, the location manager loses it's delegate and your application crashes once the location manager tries to access it's delegate.

You should properly clean up the location manager.

In -dealloc, in your *page*—probably a UIViewController—set something like (and this is just a start):

```
- (void) dealloc {
    //todo: stop updating/release the location manager too
    [self.locationManager setDelegate:nil];

    //there should be a lot more code here

    [super dealloc];
}
```

You should properly manage your objects and your location manager in particular though. You should read Apple's [Delegates and Data Sources](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/DelegatesandDataSources/DelegatesandDataSources.html) documentation and Apple's [Memory Management guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011-SW1).